# Телеграмм бот с таймаутом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Есть короче такая проблема, я создал в цикле while true функцию которая каждую минуту у всех пользователей бд отнимает 1 в значении timeout. Когда запуская код, бот не запускается, почему то запускается только цикл while true. Кто-нибудь знает как сделать чтобы и while true и запуск бота работали вместе.

```
from db import Database
import sqlite3
import random
import time

from aiogram import executor

conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
mem_time = time.perf_counter()


TOKEN="my bot token"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

db = Database('database.db')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    user2 = message.from_user.username
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id,message.from_user.username)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Регистрация завершена, ваш никнейм: {user2}")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f"Вы уже зарегестрированы, ваш никнейм: {user2}")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['addcoins'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    user3 = message.from_user.id
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id,message.from_user.username)
        user2 = message.from_user.username
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Регистрация завершена, ваш никнейм: {user2}")
    else:
        quary3 = 'SELECT timeout FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
        cur.execute(quary3)
        time = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
        if time <= 0:
            worl = random.randint(1,3)
            if worl == 3:
                timeout = 30 #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                int(timeout)
                cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET timeout = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (timeout, user3))
                conn.commit()
                quary = 'SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
                cur.execute(quary)
                coins = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
                coinsadd = random.randint(1, 10)
                coins -= coinsadd
                cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET coins = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (coins, user3))
                conn.commit()
                quary1 = 'SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
                cur.execute(quary1)
                coins = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
                quary2 = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
                cur.execute(quary2)
                user_n_ame = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'*{user_n_ame}* потеряли *{coinsadd}*, Ваш баланс *{coins}*  ',parse_mode="Markdown")

            else:
                quary = 'SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
                cur.execute(quary)
                coins5 = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
                coins3 = random.randint(1,10)
                coins5 += coins3
                cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET coins = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (coins5, user3))
                conn.commit()
                quary = 'SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
                cur.execute(quary)
                coins = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
                quary1 = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
                cur.execute(quary1)
                user_n_ame = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'*{user_n_ame}* получил(a) *{coins3}*, Ваш баланс *{coins}* ',parse_mode="Markdown")
        else:
            quary2 = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
            cur.execute(quary2)
            user_n_ame = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
            quary3 = 'SELECT timeout FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
            cur.execute(quary3)
            time_left = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'*{user_n_ame}*, вы сможете повторить эту команду через {time_left} минут(ы)',parse_mode="Markdown")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['clear_balance'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    user3 = message.from_user.id
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id,message.from_user.username)
        user2 = message.from_user.username
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Регистрация завершена, ваш никнейм: {user2}")
    else:
        coins = 0
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET coins = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (coins, user3))
        conn.commit()
        quary = 'SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
        cur.execute(quary)
        coins5 = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
        quary2 = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
        cur.execute(quary2)
        user_n_ame = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f'*{user_n_ame} *Ваш баланс *{coins5}* ',parse_mode="Markdown")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['set_nickname'])
async def profile(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id,message.from_user.username)
        user2 = message.from_user.username
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Регистрация завершена, ваш никнейм: {user2}")

    else:
        newname = message.text[14:]
        if newname != '':
            query = "UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE user_id =  ?"
            cur.execute(query, (newname, message.from_user.id))
            conn.commit()
            user3 = message.from_user.id
            quary1 = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user3)
            cur.execute(quary1)
            username = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
            await message.reply(f"Имя успешно сменено, ваш новый никнейм: *{username}*",parse_mode="Markdown")
        else:
            await message.reply("Введите не пустое имя!")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['profile'])  # Функция просмотра профиля
async def profile(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id,message.from_user.username)
        user2 = message.from_user.username
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Регистрация завершена, ваш никнейм: {user2}")

    else:
        user1 = message.from_user.id
        quary = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user1)
        cur.execute(quary)
        username = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
        quary1 = 'SELECT coins FROM users WHERE user_id =' + str(user1)
        cur.execute(quary1)
        coins5 = int(cur.fetchone()[0])
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Аккаунт пользователя *{username}* \nВаши монеты: *{coins5}* \n  ',parse_mode="Markdown")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['clear_timeout'])  # Функция просмотра профиля
async def profile(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id,message.from_user.username)
        user2 = message.from_user.username
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Регистрация завершена, ваш никнейм: {user2}")

    else:
        time = 0
        user3 = message.from_user.id
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE users SET timeout = ? WHERE user_id = ?', (time, user3))
        conn.commit()

while True:
    cur_time = time.perf_counter()
    if cur_time - mem_time >= 60:
        print('1 minute')
        mem_time = cur_time
        query = f"UPDATE users SET timeout = timeout - 1 WHERE user_id > 0"
        cur.execute(query)
        conn.commit()

from aiogram import executor
executor.start_polling(dp,  skip_updates = True)
```

Вот файл db:

```
import sqlite3



class Database:
    def __init__(self,db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()




    def add_user(self, user_id,user_username):
        with self.connection:
            sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO users
                                  (user_id,username)
                                  VALUES (?,?);"""
            data_tuple = (user_id, user_username)
            self.cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)



    def user_exists(self,user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))
```

[image: бд таблица]

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btelegram-bot%5d%20schedule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл не дает работать все что ниже него. Если я правильно понял вашу потребность, то это решение вам подойдет :

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

async def func_1():    
    print('1 minute')
    mem_time = cur_time
    query = f"UPDATE users SET timeout = timeout - 1 WHERE user_id > 0"
    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(func_1, 'interval', seconds=60)
    scheduler.start()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Теперь да, кажду минуту отнимается еденичка, но бот не запускается. Интересненько почему так

Comment: потому что нужно было асинхронно делать=) Я тоже не такой уж знаток пайтона, сам пока учусь. Функцию изменил, по идее должно заработать.

Comment: спасибки большое))))

Comment: не забудьте отметить, что мой ответ правильный)